# How to collect frequencies of characters using a list of tuples {char,freq} in Erlang

Tags: erlang, tuples

I am supposed to collect frequencies of characters.

```
freq(Sample) -> freq(Sample,[]).

freq([],Freq) ->
    Freq;
freq([Char|Rest],Freq)->
    freq(Rest,[{Char,1}|Freq]).
```

This function does not work in the right way. If the input is "foo", then the output will be
    [{f,1},{o,1},{o,1}]. 
But I wished to have the output like 
    [{f,1},{o,2}]. 
I can't manage to modify element in a tulpe. Can anyone help me out of this and show me how it can be fixed?

Comment: Have a look at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Erlang for some inspiration

Comment: Use `orddict:update_counter/3`.

Answer (score 3):

a one line solution :o)

```
% generate a random list
L = [random:uniform(26)+$a-1 || _ <- lists:seq(1,1000)].

% collect frequency
lists:foldl(fun(X,[{[X],I}|Q]) -> [{[X],I+1}|Q] ; (X,Acc) -> [{[X],1}|Acc] end , [], lists:sort(L)).
```

in action

```
1> lists:foldl(fun(X,[{[X],I}|Q]) -> [{[X],I+1}|Q] ; (X,Acc) -> [{[X],1}|Acc] end , [], lists:sort("foo")).
[{"o",2},{"f",1}]
```

quite fast with short list, but the execution time increase a lot with long list (on my PC, it needs 6.5s for a 1 000 000 character text) .

in comparison, with the same 1 000 000 character text Ricardo solution needs 5 sec

I will try another version using ets.

Comment: +1 @Pascal: Wow! That's better pattern matching. I am learning and thank you for showing better ways :).

Answer (score 3):

By far the easiest way is to use an `orddict` to store the value as it already comes with an `update_counter` function and returns the value in a (sorted) list.

```
freq(Text) ->
    lists:foldl(fun (C, D) -> orddict:update_counter(C, 1, D) end, orddict:new(), Text).
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like this:

```erlang
freq(Text) ->
    CharsDictionary = lists:foldl(fun(Char, Acc) -> dict:update_counter(Char, 1, Acc) end, dict:new(), Text),
    dict:fold(fun(Char, Frequency, Acc) -> [{Char, Frequency} | Acc] end, [], CharsDictionary).
```

The first line creates a dictionary that uses the char as key and the frequency as value ([dict:update_counter](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dict.html#update_counter-3)).

The second line converts the dictionary in the list that you need.

Comment: I have fixed the problem with an additional function.　But thanks for helping anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Using pattern matching and proplists.

```
-module(freq).
-export([char_freq/1]).

-spec char_freq(string()) -> [tuple()].
char_freq(L) -> char_freq(L, []).

char_freq([], PL) -> PL;
char_freq([H|T], PL) ->
    case proplists:get_value([H], PL) of
        undefined ->
            char_freq(T, [{[H],1}|PL]);
        N ->
            L = proplists:delete([H], PL),
            char_freq(T, [{[H],N+1}|L])
    end.
```

Test

```
1> freq:char_freq("abacabz").
[{"z",1},{"b",2},{"a",3},{"c",1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [list_to_atom(X) || X <- Str].
D = lists:foldl(fun({Char, _}, Acc) -> dict:update_counter(Char, 1, Acc) end, dict:new(), L).
dict:to_list(D).
```